# How to enable Media info view for Kodi video add-on?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I am creating list items with `xbmcgui.ListItem()` but I can not switch list view to Media view in GUI. Looks like only List, Big list, Thumbnail and Wide views are available.

Basically I would like to make something like in TestTube addon. It switches to Media view by default.

Here is printscreen of TestTube view: http://prntscr.com/7mvy9j

Answer (score 1):

You should call

> xbmcplugin.setContent(addon_handle, 'movies')